# Assign a standard jQuery function to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I assign these functions `submit()` and `click()` to a variable. So that I can use them in an if statement like this:

```
function sendToCheckout() {
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    if($("form[action='/cart']").length == 1){
      var x = submit();
    }
    else {
      var x = click();
    }
    $("form[action='/cart']").off().x(function(event){
      event.preventDefault(event);
      var amountToSend = sessionStorage.getItem('amountToSend');
        if(amountToSend != null && amountToSend != "0"){
          sendData();         
        }
        else{
          window.location.href = shopAddress + "/checkout";
        }      
    });
  });
}
```

With the above code I got the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: submit is not defined`

Comment: By taking the `()` off of them

Comment: And use `on(event, eventHandler)` not `.variablename(`

Comment: Listening for click on form doesn't really make sense. Why would you need that? This seems like an XY Problem

Comment: Though, when would it ever be the case that the `else` would happen that then the binding would make sense?  If the `else` happens, there isn't an element to bind on

Comment: The code's not 100% complete. I'll just assign another element to bind too.. thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions are also the names of events, so you can work with them that way.

Assign the event name as a string, then use `.on()`, which takes the event name as a parameter.

You also shouldn't have multiple `var x` declarations. Declare it before the `if`, then assign it in it.

```js
function sendToCheckout() {
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var x;
    if ($("form[action='/cart']").length == 1) {
      x = "submit";
    } else {
      x = "click";
    }
    $("form[action='/cart']").off().on(x, function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(event);
      var amountToSend = sessionStorage.getItem('amountToSend');
      if (amountToSend != null && amountToSend != "0") {
        sendData();
      } else {
        window.location.href = shopAddress + "/checkout";
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Calling `off()` with no event names seems sketchy

Comment: There's lots of sketchy stuff here, see the comments below the question.